# Propiedades Estáticas en Clases Genéricas de un Type a partir de un Object

Tags: c#

Me gustaría acceder a las propiedades, campos o métodos estáticos de una clase genérica, si conozco el Type no hay problema pero el tema es que no solo lo desconozco sino que lo debo obtener a partir de un objeto.

```
public Animal<T>{
       public static int Velocidad = 3;
       //...
}

public class Main{
     List<object> ListaAnimales = new List<object>(){new Animal<Pajaro>(), 
     new Animal<Perro>(),new Animal<Gato>()/*..... N Animales */};

     Main(){
        Console.WriteLine(Animal<Pajaro>.Velocidad);//Funciona pero yo no se el animal
        //¿Cómo accedo a la Velocidad del object animal?
        object animal = ListaAnimal[new Random().Next(ListaAnimal.Count)];
        Console.WriteLine(Animal</*Como coloco el Type a partir del object*/>.Velocidad);
     }
}
```

El Campo Velocidad tiene que ser estático porque la clase se instancia sobre 1.000 veces y son distintos tipos(T) de clases. Trate con Interfaces pero no funciona en Métodos estáticos.

Comment: La velocidad Son Todos distintas o Independientes de cada animal. Necesito acceder a esa Velocidad(que para hacer simple el ejemplo son todos 3) y otros campos estáticos por medio del object animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las soluciones sería hacerlo mediante `Reflection` como ya te han comentado, pero creo que no sería la más óptima.

Podrías hacerlo mediante Interfaces, creando una interfaz para declarar una propiedad que te devuelva la velocidad e implementándola en la clase de Animal.

Sería algo así:

```
public interface IVelocidad
{
    int GetVelocidad { get; }
}


public class Animal<T> : IVelocidad
{
    public static int velocidad = 3;

    //Propiedad de ejemplo
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int GetVelocidad
    {
        get
        {
            return velocidad;
        }
    }
}
```

Y luego en tu Main solo encesitarías modificar esta linea apra que quede así:

```
//object animal = ListaAnimal[new Random().Next(ListaAnimal.Count)];

IVelocidad animal = ListaAnimal[new Random().Next(ListaAnimal.Count)];
int laVelocidad = animal.GetVelocidad();
```

Comment: Después de mucho buscar y antes de publicar me había planteado esta opción pero no la quería usar porque eran cerca de 30 Propiedades Estáticas a las que tendría que crearle el mismo numero de Propiedades No-Estáticas para Acceder/Modicarlos, sin embargo, Acabo de implementarlo y funciona todo correctamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La única manera que existe para hacer lo que necesitas es mediante [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173183(v=vs.110).aspx) ya que el tipo se conocerá en tiempo de ejecución y no en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: Si necesitas mas ayuda con la reflexión coméntalo y te lo detallo más.

Comment: Son muchos Nodos a los que accedo a su "Velocidad" permanentemente y se notaria el retraso al hacerlo con Reflection. Me quedo con la opción de @miguel. Gracias ;)